# Laravel Homestead on Windows 10 - Need to append port

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

So I setup my homestead on a Win 10 machine and it seems like I find myself with this issue every now and then.

What happens is, homestead works just fine for a few days then all of a sudden, when I start it up, I can no longer access `http://local.domain.dev` (which is what I mapped to the IP `192.168.10.10`) without appending it with port `8000`.

I really don't get it. I think it has something to do with Windows updates? Although I can't really tell since Win 10 updates are so, I dunno, sneaky? I never know when there were updates until I see it on the notification bar. Most of the time, it doesn't tell you it's updating during bootup like Win 7 did.

In any case, this is really becoming a pain since having the domain is important to some of the features of the site I'm working on and specifying a port somehow screws it up (whole different story, don't ask).

So, I guess I'm asking if anyone else is experiencing the same issues on their Windows 10 machine and if they have a permanent fix to this?

This issue has popped up every now and then since I've upgraded to Win 10 and the last time had this issue, what I did to fix it was to update Vagrant and VBox.

I have `Vagrant 1.7.4` and `VBox 5.0.4`, I think those are still the latest ones.

Comment: The latest one for virtual box is Vbox 5.0.6. :). I've just reinstalled my pc with win 10 and it works great. without any setup like before (using :8000)

Comment: Ok, I'll try installing the latest VBOx again. Not sure what's going on though.

Comment: It worked for a couple of days and now it's back again. Am I really the only one around here experiencing this issue?!

Comment: I'm having the exact same thing happening now. No clue where its coming from. It was working yesterday